# How to access a form array from different buttons in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm learning vb.net and have a problem. Short version of code.

I have structure like this:

```
public class form234

public array1() as string

public sub button1

    Dim i As Integer
            Dim array1(Len(text)) As String
            For i = 1 To 3
                array1(i) = "x"
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & array1(i) & " "
            Next
```

When I put a msgbox here I get the content of my array

......

```
public sub button2
```

When I put a msgbox here I get error and array1 is "nothing"

...........

Why? How can I use my array value of sub button1 in sub button 2 as well?

Comment: In `Sub button1` you have declared *another* array named "array1". It is not the same variable as the "array1" which is declared in the class. Please google for "vb.net variable scope" to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write that as:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ReDim array1(Text.Length)
    For i As Integer = 0 To array1.Length - 1
        array1(i) = "x"
        TextBox2.Text = String.Join(" ", array1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you declared a second time your array1 in public sub button1.

if you want really to use the one that you declared public, you have to give him a size, the thing that you can do in his first declaration.

Else an alternative solution can be :

```
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Array.Resize(array1, Len(Text))
    For i = 1 To 3
        array1(i) = "x"
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & array1(i) & " "
    Next
```